# iOS Swift: How to check if port is open

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, port, asyncsocket

In my application want to check port is open or not. Here refer this link

> [iOS SDK: How can I check if a port is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329723/ios-sdk-how-can-i-check-if-a-port-is-open)

But dnt get any solution. And also refer these two github source,

> https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket
>
> https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

But dnt any solution. Any one help how check port is open or not. Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please use the below method to port is open or not**

```
func isPortOpen(port: in_port_t) -> Bool {

    let socketFileDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    if socketFileDescriptor == -1 {
        return false
    }

    var addr = sockaddr_in()
    let sizeOfSockkAddr = MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size
    addr.sin_len = __uint8_t(sizeOfSockkAddr)
    addr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    addr.sin_port = Int(OSHostByteOrder()) == OSLittleEndian ? _OSSwapInt16(port) : port
    addr.sin_addr = in_addr(s_addr: inet_addr("0.0.0.0"))
    addr.sin_zero = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    var bind_addr = sockaddr()
    memcpy(&bind_addr, &addr, Int(sizeOfSockkAddr))

    if Darwin.bind(socketFileDescriptor, &bind_addr, socklen_t(sizeOfSockkAddr)) == -1 {
        return false
    }
    if listen(socketFileDescriptor, SOMAXCONN ) == -1 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Use like:**

```
let port = UInt16(10000)
print(isPortOpen(port:port))
```

Comment: addr.sin_addr = in_addr(s_addr: inet_addr("0.0.0.0")) and  addr.sin_zero = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) in this two line for 0 what i want to add? help me?

Comment: Just replace "0.0.0.0" with your socket URL for example 127.0.0.1 for localhost rest of thing keep as it is

Comment: addr.sin_zero = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) in this line what i should add for 0?

Comment: how to get socket URL help me?

Comment: can u reply my question?

Comment: This answer leaves each port that is check in an opened state and listens to it, which is probably not what you want. The other answer shows how to close the port after checking.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot add comments, so I am adding this as a separate answer. I followed Surani's answer, but encountered errors when using the port later in the application. I found I had to manually close the socket before returning the response.

So I modified the last 4 lines to

```
    let isOpen = listen(socketFileDescriptor, SOMAXCONN ) != -1
    Darwin.close(socketFileDescriptor)
    return isOpen
```

Here is the revised version of Surani's answer with the socket closing code

```
func isPortOpen(port: in_port_t) -> Bool {

    let socketFileDescriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    if socketFileDescriptor == -1 {
        return false
    }

    var addr = sockaddr_in()
    let sizeOfSockkAddr = MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size
    addr.sin_len = __uint8_t(sizeOfSockkAddr)
    addr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
    addr.sin_port = Int(OSHostByteOrder()) == OSLittleEndian ? _OSSwapInt16(port) : port
    addr.sin_addr = in_addr(s_addr: inet_addr("0.0.0.0"))
    addr.sin_zero = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    var bind_addr = sockaddr()
    memcpy(&bind_addr, &addr, Int(sizeOfSockkAddr))

    if Darwin.bind(socketFileDescriptor, &bind_addr, socklen_t(sizeOfSockkAddr)) == -1 {
        return false
    }
    let isOpen = listen(socketFileDescriptor, SOMAXCONN ) != -1
    Darwin.close(socketFileDescriptor)
    return isOpen
}
```

Use like:

```
let port = UInt16(10000)
print(isPortOpen(port:port))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped free up the port after the check.